# Use FutureBuilder to display a list of items stored in a database in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

Here `dishType` is a variable that stores the items with the `Dish` type to be displayed,
It is showing an empty list.

Following is the body of my `FutureBuilder`

```
 body: FutureBuilder<List>(
    future: dishes(),
    initialData: List(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                final item = snapshot.data[index];
                if (item.dishType == dishType) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("${item.dishName}"),
                      subtitle: Text(item.dishType),
                    );
                } else return null;
              },
      )
          : Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Here is a screenshot of the output after the if the condition is removed

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If I remove the if statement it works properly showing a list of all dishes and their types.

Comment: Probably the dishType has different values, put a print statement and check both values

Comment: I did so they are exactly the same

Comment: I also tried putting them in subtitle of the LIstTile the are exactly same

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/log of those printed values

Comment: @MidhunMP Yeah Sure

Comment: I have added the SS of the OutPut becuase the log was just printing the values again and again

Comment: Change your if statement like: if (item.dishType.toUpperCase() == dishType.toUpperCase()) and let us know whether it worked or not

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks a Lot! It seems item.dishType was not a string even though dishType is a String Property. I tried doing item.dishType.toUpperString() but it suggested . toString and now it works perfectly. Thanks Again.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy Coding!!! :)

Comment: the return null at the end of the item builder was creating the problem. it seems the item builder ended once it reached that statement. Instead I returned an empty widget and it works...